# Saving a Jupyter notebook causes SSH connection to be "closed by remote"

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ssh-tunnel

I am working remotely on a Jupyter notebook, connecting from a Mac to a remote Ubuntu.  The method I use (which I always use) is

1. run `jupyter notebook --no-browser` on the remote machine
2. use SSH tunnel to forward local port `PORT` to remote.
3. Open `localhost:PORT` in a local browser and work on a notebook.

The problem is that for a *specific* notebook, whenever I try to save it, the SSH connection used for the port forwarding is "closed by remote host". This is a new problem, that is I worked on this notebook many times in the past and there was no such problem. I noticed that this does *not* happen if I create a new, empty notebook - just for a specific notebook. I tried to make a copy of the notebook, and the problem still happens.

**EDIT** another detail: the notebook does not get saved when the remote connection is closed.